# How to hide JavaScript code when i do inspect element using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

when I do inspect element I want my javascript code to be shown on the minified way. How to do it using angular?

Comment: just comment it out, can you give more details?

Comment: Angular doesn't minify code. You need a post processor to do that.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible at all. If all you want is hide app logic from end user, don't run that code on the user's machine. Instead use server side like plain old php.

Answer (score 2):

As said by others that Angular js doesn't minify code. One of the best solution is to obfuscate code by using obfuscation tool:
https://javascriptobfuscator.com/protect-javascript.aspx

It also Uglifies the code too, resulting in an obfuscated, minified JS file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't minify code using Angular.js, you will need a post processor to do that. https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2 is a good option, depending on your setup you can run it from command line or using a build tool like gulp.js.

It's important to understand, that even minified code can most likely be reverse engineered. Security relevant parts of the code that should never be seen by user have to be server side.